# How to save matplotlib chart to temporary file in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, praat

I need to save a Matplot plot to a temporary file that I control since this code would be in a python Flask REST service.

I tried this:

fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
return_base64 = ""

```
with fp:
    fp.write(plt.savefig) # THIS IS WRONG....
    with open(fp.name, 'rb') as open_it:
        open_it.seek(0)
        return_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(open_it.read()))
        # strip off leading b and ' and trailing '
        return_base64 = return_base64[2: len(return_base64) - 1]
        open_it.close()
    fp.close()
```

But, "fp.write" doesn't work with saving the plt.savefig as I did above.

My issue is that I'm using the PRAAT phonetic library and there does not seem to be a way to use the "Sound()" method inside a REST service. Thus, I'm doing lots of temporary files to work around this.

So, how do I write the matplotib plot to a named temporary file?

Appreciation and thanks in advance.

Comment: in what way does that address my question?

Comment: sorry my bad. didn't completely read your question

Comment: is there any practical use of temp module ? i think normal `open` will work . `fp.write()` use `bytes` to write and you assigning just function `plt.savefig ` . other suggestion is you don't have to strip string manually you can use `return_base64.decode()` will return string .

Comment: How do I get the "bytes" from the plt.savefig? I don't see any way to get the bytes from the plt object.

Comment: It's confusing why "plt.savefig(fp.name)" doesn't work. The fp.name specifies a temporary path, but after this runs doing an "ls -la" on that temp file shows zero bytes.

Comment: @Morkus I don't know  more about it. but i am guessing you can use `io` for getting bytes from that image or plot  like this `import io  buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
buf.seek(0)
print(buf.getvalue())` now `buf.getvalue()` return plot bytes you can save in file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am sharing this code it is storing jpg file in my temporary folder

```
import io 

buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format="jpg")
#print(buf.getvalue()) return bytes of plot 

fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() 

# print(fp.name) return file name 

with open(f"{fp.name}.jpg",'wb') as ff:
    ff.write(buf.getvalue()) 

buf.close()
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I don't really need the temp file as I can just return the buf as base64 encoded I think.